# Change color when onmouseover

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I want to change the color of a piece from image when `onmouseover` but not received:

My code:

```
<img src="demo_usa.png" width="960" height="593" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">
<map name="planetmap" id="map">
    <area id="myMap" shape="rect"  coords="0,0,120,126" alt="Sun" href="#" 
    onMouseOver="colorSwitch(this.id, '#ff9999');" />   
</map>

<script type="text/javascript">
function colorSwitch(id, color) {
    element = document.getElementById(id);
    element.style.background = color;
}
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `area` element has no `id`, yet you pass in `this.id`

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20127935/area-shape-in-html

Comment: @TheMonk No duplicate, the problem here is the id, the JavaScript is implemented.

Comment: Like this:
function colorSwitch(id, color) {
    element = document.getElementById('map' + id);
    element.style.background = color;
}
<map name="planetmap" id="myMap">
   <area id="map" shape="rect"  coords="0,0,120,126" alt="Sun" href="#"
    onMouseOver="colorSwitch(this.id, '#ff3451');" />   
   
</map>

Answer (score 0):

Areas cannot have background colours; try this:

```
<div id="planetmap">
    <img id="backgroundimage" src="demo_usa.png" width="960" height="593" alt="Planets"/>
    <div id="planet.1" class="planetmarker" style="left:0px;top:0px;width:120px;height:126px;">
    </div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
    .planetmarker {
        position: absolute;
        z-index:1;
    }

    .planetmarker:hover {
        background-color: #ff9999;
    }
</style>
```

You can alternatively also use JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setOpacity(id, level) {
        element = document.getElementById(id);
        element.style.opacity = level;
    }
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .planetmarker {
        position: absolute;
        z-index:1;
        background-color: #ff9999;
        opacity: 0;
    }
</style>
<div id="planetmap">
    <img id="backgroundimage" src="demo_usa.png" width="960" height="593" alt="Planets"/>
    <div id="planet.1" class="planetmarker" style="left:0px;top:0px;width:120px;height:126px;" onMouseOver="setOpacity(this.id, 1);" onMouseLeave="setOpacity(this.id, 0);">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @user2993914 sorry fixed

Comment: function colorSwitch(id, color) {
    element = document.getElementById('map' + id);
    element.style.background = color;
}

Comment: @user2993914 remove the 'map'.

Comment: @user2993914 There you go.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

**HTML:**

```
<area shape="rect"  coords="0,0,120,126" alt="Sun" href="#"
  onMouseOver="colorSwitch('map', '#ff9999');" />
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function colorSwitch(id, color)
 {
   element = document.getElementById( id );
   element.style.background = color;
 }
</script>
```

Note that `this.id` will send the id of the element `<area ..>` that is null in the code.. You need to send the string as the id of the `map` element